# Best permission settings for a separate data partition to prevent access if computer is hacked?

Tags: linux, permissions, security

I have two partitions on my system:

- Kubuntu (ext4)
- DATA (vfat), which stores all my files

I want to make sure that no-one but I can access the DATA partition in the event of my house being burgled or so...
Note: I have a password on my Linux system.

Say, someone used a Linux Live Disk (Ubuntu or any), and tried to access my DATA partition:

How can I make sure they cannot read, write etc. my files on my DATA partition?

Is 770 the correct permission?

Comment: Data will be accessible by root (or somebody escalating privileges or having access to the physical disk) unless you encrypt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permissions or ACLs won't help here, since an attacker can simply boot a Live USB Linux distro on your machine, or remount the physical disk on another computer, to have full access to all your files.

You need instead to have full disk encryption on your data partition (even better, on the whole disk), and [LUKS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) is the easiest way to do so.